# How to manage exceptions in a long call stack

Tags: java, exceptions

When throw a exception inside java method, IntelliJ suggest to add exception to method signature. When I have a long call-stack as below how I manage these exceptions.

`method 1() -> method 2() -> method 3() -> method 4()`

Method 1 calling method 2 and method 2 calling method 3 and so on.

Lets say method 4 throw `InvalidDataException`. Then as IDE suggest I have to add exception to all the method signatures.

Assume method 4 returning a value and this value comes until method 1.

So what is the best approach to solve this? Should I add exception to all the method signatures or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You should probably disable the suggestion. :D

Comment: Eclipse suggests to either add a throws clause to the method (signature), or surround the possible source of exception in a try catch block.

Comment: That's not a suggestion. It's a compiler error that eclipse shows within the IDE.

Comment: @marstato, how do you know that? OP didn't mention anything about the exception being a checked one (also, OP seems to be using IntelliJ, not Eclipse). And if that's the case and the exception really is checked, the actual question probably is: why should the exception be checked in the first place?

Comment: @Andy oh, jep, no idea where it got eclipse from. But anyways: i don't know how OPs intellij is configured. Though i'm pretty sure the default settings do not put out that suggestion for unchecked exceptions. At least my IntelliJ setups certainly never do.
Plus that wording sounds very much like the javac error message.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn’t matter one bit how long the call stack is.

Method A calls method B which could throw an exception. Method A has three choices: It can be written in such a way that it can let an exception pass through to its own caller without code handling it at all. Or it can catch the exception, handle it completely and not pass it on - that’s what you do if you know how to handle the exception. Or it catches the exception, takes actions to make its own code work fine, and retries the exception, possibly modified. That’s what you need to do.

Now if you have a long call chain, that just means that you may have more methods that can throw exceptions. You need to do the steps that I described in each method that calls another method that can throw.

Important: Any method that has no exception handling code must be written in such a way that everything works fine if an exception is passed through. That’s the developer’s job. Garbage collection in Java and destructors for stack variables in C++ help.

Comment: + 1 for "It doesn’t matter one bit how long the call stack is." Also the exception stack could contain exceptions for many classes belonging to frameworks, the JDK, external libraries, etc. including unchecked exceptions like null pointer etc.

Answer (score 3):

Us usual, there is no single best way.

What IntelliJ suggests (and it offers more options than just adding it to the method signature) are only ways that are simple mechanical fixes.

We'd need to more know about your project, your architecture, etc. to determine what the best approach *for your software*, *given your current knowledge* would be. That approach may change tomorrow though when you learn something new or get other requirements.

Generally, I commend you for recognizing the simple solution as a bad idea. Yes, just adding `throws` declarations to hundreds of methods certainly isn't a very appealing solution. In order to find other approaches to error handling, there are a few guiding questions you can ask:

- What sort of error are you thinking about here? Is it an inconvenience, does it reduce the service's capabilities, does it outright crash and stop your software from working,...
- Who is this error relevant to? Is it something the user needs to see, or something that operations needs to know about, or will only developers be interested in it?
- How should the error be treated? Is it enough to just catch an exception and do some logging? do you need to dynamically modify your program behavior (f.ex. to work around a 3rd party service being offline)? do you need to translate your error into some other domain (f.ex. turn an authorization-related exception to the proper HTTP error code)

After you got an idea to the answers for these questions, there's a whole other bunch of questions you can ask to narrow down the best technical solution. Read up on different error handling approaches if you don't already know a bunch of them - here's just a starter: Validation/Either objects (or more generally monads), HTTP filters, checked or unchecked exceptions, ... and then there's a whole line of thinking on how to design your programs such that things you thought about as "error" become normal and need not even be treated in any exceptional way.

Answer (score 3):

Where to handle an exception depends on what your possible options are when an error arises.

A `DateFormatError` presumably arises from invalid input data. If it is possible to correct the invalid data automatically (maybe there are two possible date formats and you don't know which occurs until you try it), it makes sense to catch the exception immediately and retry with the other option.

If this isn't possible, you must propagate the exception until you have reached a point in your algorithm where a useful reaction is possible. For instance, if the date format error arises during handling one particular record in a batch of multiple records, then you should probably simply skip that record and continue with the next one. That means that the exception should propagate up until it reaches the loop over all records, and be handled with a `continue`.

This means that some exceptions travel far and some don't. The fact that Java forces you to declare some Exceptions ("checked" exceptions) in the header of every method that might raise them and that this somewhat obfuscates your code is a Java-specific issue (which is now widely considered a mistake) that shouldn't confuse the general principle.

Answer (score 2):

Handling exceptions in every level of the call stack would largely defeat their purpose. It would not be much different from handling classic error codes. Exceptions were introduced to address this very plumbing issue, to get rid of this handling logic on every level that often serves no logical purpose.

You only catch and handle exceptions at the command level, where you start an operation that is not supposed to fail but if it does you have some fall back plan. I guess your IDE just offers a helping hand for implementing exception handling logic. It remains up to you to decide where to apply it though.

Comment: Note that Swift does indeed throw errors, not exceptions, and the need to be handled at each level. I assume they thought very hard about and came to the result that this is better.

Answer (score 1):

Just because a method returns a value does not mean success.

Many values reject the assumption made by the query.

You can return an empty string, an empty collection, a maybe monad, a null object pattern, etc. So long as the code that uses the value return behaves well it doesn't mater. Exceptions are not the only way to deal with a failure.

Another option is to recover. Failing quietly is sometimes desirable. Logging can help.

But there are also times when the thing to do is roll over and die. When the system can't be put back into a well defined stable state it's better to die before you start mangling the database or sending the president threatening emails. Just crash and wait for the restart.

It's also worth noting that you don't have to slap exceptions on the signatures of every method that might do that. Just use unchecked exceptions.

Checked exception signatures are there to remind people that they may need to catch and recover from the exception the method might through. Don't tell them to do that if that isn't what they should do. Use unchecked exceptions when it’s time to die or when something in the code needs to be fixed.

Comment: Exception doesn’t even mean error in all cases. Http has no error codes, but status codes, and for a reason.